# Why does the number of lines of output file generated differ

Tags: regex, linux, perl

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use strict;
use warnings;
die "Usage: $0 FILENAMEs" if not @ARGV;
my $ni= 10;
my $fi=10;
my $flag =0;
my $ni1=10;
my $fi1 =10;
foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
open my $fh,"<$file.a" or die;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
if ($line =~ /count/) {
my @ores = split /:/, $line, 2;
if( $file eq "k4" and $flag ==1)
{
    $ni1= $ores[1];
}
else 
{
$flag=$flag+1;
$ni= $ores[1];
print "NI--", $ni;
}
}
}
close $fh;
$flag=0;
open $fh,"<$file.b" or die;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
if ($line =~ /count/) {
my @ores = split /:/, $line, 2;
 if( $file eq "k4" and $flag ==1)
 {
    $flag = $flag+1;
    $fi1= $ores[1];
 }
 else 
 {
    $fi=$ores[1];
 print "FI--", $fi;
 }
 }
 }
  close $fh;
  open($fh, ">>$file.log") or die "Could not open file '$file'.log $!";
 if($file eq "k4")
 {
 print $fh " First Instance of K4 \n-----------------------------------\n";
  }
 if( $ni > $fi)
 {
  print $fh " FI: ", $fi;
  print $fh " NI: ", $ni;
  print $fh " NI is more than FI by: ", $ni-$fi;
  }
 else
 {
    print $fh " FI: ", $fi;
  print $fh " NI: ", $ni;
  print $fh " FI is more than NI by: ",$fi-$ni;
  }
 if( $file eq "k4")
 {
 print $fh "\n Second instance of K4"; 
 if($ni1 > $fi1)
 {
    print $fh " FI: ", $fi1;
    print $fh "\n NI: ", $ni1;
    print $fh " NI is more than FI by: ", $ni1-$fi1;
  }
  else
  {
     print $fh " FI: ", $fi1;
     print $fh "\n NI: ", $ni1;
     print $fh " FI is more than NI by: ",$fi1-$ni1;
  }
  }
  }
```

The code above takes a file file1.a and file1.b, searches for lines with the word count. For each such line, the code then gets the second value of the list split by ":" and compares the values from file1.a and file1.b
Ex: File1:

```
Loops count : 12345
```

File 2:

```
Roots count : 45679
```

Output file ( file1.log):

```
 FI:  45679 
 NI:  12345 
 FI is more than NI by: 33334
```

But why does this happen?

```
$wc -l file1.log 
2 file1.log
```

( the line count should be 3. New lines at the end of the last line are absent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented, `wc -l` returns the newline count, i.e. the number of newlines, not the number of lines.